# 101 points but not allowed to answer?

Tags: support, answers, protected-questions

I tried to give an answer to [What to call "Cancel" when "Cancel" is already the default action?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/35753/28034). I have 101 points because of my association bonus. But I didn't find the «Answer» button.

What's happening here?

Comment: Now I managed to get the reputation to answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That question has been set to **Protected**, the details around this are:

> This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers by new users. To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation on this site.

It was myself who protected that question because it had hit the top of the Stackexchange Hot Questions list and had started receiving several very poor answers from new visitors to the site.

For example [this answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/35771/3865) shows such an answer left against the question from someone who hasn't visited the site before:

> "continue" would be the appropriate word for "cancel the cancel"

That was all they left as an answer. It's not necessarily *wrong* but it's highly low quality, doesn't have any reasoning or further information and doesn't help the question asker in any way at all. The downvotes against it show such.

There are also deleted answers against that question that aren't visible to <10k viewers.

If you want to answer that question then all you need to do is to receive 10 reputation **on ux.stackexchange itself** i.e. the association bonus doesn't count because you haven't received rep on this site. That just equates to one upvoted answer on a different post. It's pretty easy to achieve but it does prevent the typical low-quality answers that tend to come in for the very popular questions, hence why certain questions get protected from time-to-time.

Comment: I posted the answer in the unprotected duplicate instead.